# XML node name and attributes are not available

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<values>
    <bool key="Chapter_1.Boolean1.value">true</bool>
    <string key="Chapter_1.Text1.value">abc</string>
    <string key="Chapter_1.Text2.value">Inspection done (2)</string>
    <number key="Chapter_1.Number1.value">128</number>
    <number key="Chapter_1.Number2.value">34539718</number>
    <number key="Chapter_1.Number3.value">3</number>
    <datetime key="Chapter_2.Chapter_2_1.DateTime1.value">2020-06-02T09:00:00+03:00</datetime>
    <datetime key="Chapter_2.Chapter_2_1.DateTime2.value">2016-02-05T00:00:00+02:00</datetime>
    <string key="Chapter_3.Text4.value">52</string>
    <string key="Chapter_3.Text5.value">22</string>
    <number key="Chapter_3.Number6.value">34539718</number>
</values>
```

and the following C# code:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
settings.IgnoreComments = true;

using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilePath))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        var nodeName = xmlReader.Name;
        var attrName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("key");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the node name is empty and there are no attributes for the following keys:

- Chapter_1.Text1.value
- Chapter_1.Number1.value
- Chapter_3.Text5.value

Anyone has any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code worked well here, I was able to access all xml tags and attributes.

Maybe you're confused because at each `xmlReader.Read()` it reads only one part of the tag. So to read all the tag with key "*Chapter_1.Text1.value*", **first** it reads a tag with **name `string` and key "*Chapter_1.Text1.value*"**, then it reads something without a name, without a attribute, but with **value "abc"** and then it reads the tag closing with **name `string`**, but no attribute and no value.

Comment: This was the issue, but in the end I replaced my implementation with the solution provided by Xiaoy312 (Xml to Linq). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use Xml to Linq :

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(__PATH_TO_XML__);
var values = xml.XPathSelectElements("/values/*")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Type = x.Name,
        Key = x.Attribute("key"),
        Value = x.Value
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using your solution. Seems more intuitive and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the value as well, try this

```
      using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(@"yourxmlfile"))
        {
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {

                    var nodeName = xmlReader.Name;
                    var attrName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("key");

                    Console.WriteLine(nodeName);
                    Console.WriteLine(attrName);

                }
                if (xmlReader.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```